# Make text Invisible with font-lock-keywords

Tags: org-mode, faces, font-lock, text-properties

I'm interested in changing my org-mode buffers to have a better looking logbook. My ideal state to end up in is that text that looks like this:

```
- State "WAITING"    from "WAITING"    [2018-11-16 Fri 16:00] \\
  description of why this task is still waiting
- State "WAITING"    from "WAITING"    [2018-11-16 Fri 11:20]
- State "WAITING"    from "NEXT"       [2018-11-15 Thu 11:55] \\
  Addressed feedback Bump on 2018-11-19 if not approved yet.
```

instead is formatted to look like this

```
- WAITING [2018-11-16 Fri 16:00] \\
  description of why this task is still waiting
- WAITING [2018-11-16 Fri 11:20]
- WAITING [2018-11-15 Thu 11:55] \\
  Addressed feedback Bump on 2018-11-19 if not approved yet.
```

I've gotten pretty close to  what I want with this code:

```
(defface mjh-subdued `((t :background ,mjh-base03 :foreground ,mjh-base02))
    "Subdued face for text that shouldn't be very visible.")
(font-lock-add-keywords
   'org-mode
   '(
     ("\\(State +\"\\)\\(TODO\\)\\(\" +from.*\\)$"     (1 'mjh-subdued) (2 'mjh-subdued)  (3 'mjh-subdued))
     ("\\(State +\"\\)\\(NEXT\\)\\(\" +from.*\\)$"     (1 'mjh-subdued) (2 'mjh-subdued)  (3 'mjh-subdued))
     ("\\(State +\"\\)\\(WAITING\\)\\(\" +from.*\\)$"  (1 'mjh-subdued) (2 'mjh-waiting)  (3 'mjh-subdued))
     ("\\(State +\"\\)\\(DONE\\)\\(\" +from.*\\)$"     (1 'mjh-subdued) (2 'mjh-subdued)  (3 'mjh-subdued))
     ("\\(State +\"\\)\\(CANCELED\\)\\(\" +from.*\\)$" (1 'mjh-subdued) (2 'mjh-canceled) (3 'mjh-subdued))
 ))
```

With this, the text isn't invisible, but it is subdued so it doesn't draw much attention. Ideally, I want the text that is currently formatted as `mjh-subdued` to be invisible (and zero-width).

But I'm stuck. I can't figure out how to add the `'invisible` text property to the matched groups. According to [search based fontification](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html), I should be able to add text properties for the `(matcher . facespec)` form, but I can't figure out how I need to get it worked. Changing one of the `(1 'mjh-subdued)` to `(1 (face 'mjh-subdued :invisible t))` does not work. (and breaks what I *do* have working)

Any ideas on where I should look for this? I tried looking through the source for `font-lock-add-keywords`, but it's pretty dense.

I can add the code for the other faces if it matters, but they just change the `TODO` keywords to be colored differently.

Comment: Should that say `(1 (face mjh-subdued :invisible t))`  rather than `font`?